# Should I make my server program run as a Windows Service on Windows

Tags: java, windows, windows-services

My Java application is primarily a desktop application. But I have added a new option that instead it runs as a server with the UI accessible via a webbrowser over a port (uses Spark framework with embedded Jetty server)

Currently I'm just starting it up as a command line application via a batch file, to stop it I would just interrupt the batch process with Cntl-C

But should I be running it as Windows Service, if so why and how please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Windows services are native for Windows, you cannot do it directly in java. However, you can use a service wrapper application that will invoke your java application.

Take a look at Apache commons daemon's procrun:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html

Comment: Thanks thats helpful, but is it necessary, what are the advantages ?

Comment: It's not necessary... it depends on the nature of your application - a Windows service can start up automatically with the system, and can run even if no user is logged in to windows. In addition, it can auto restart your app should it crash for some reason. You can read more about it here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service).

Comment: okay I mark your answer as correct since it gives useful information and I wil come back to this at a later date.